# How to know if I will be affected by the Ryanair strike on 22nd August?

Tags: air-travel, ryanair, industrial-action

I am going on the first Ryanair flight from Hamburg to Stansted. This is the first flight of the day. I am aware of a strike on 22nd August for UK-based Ryanair crew.

Is there anyway to check if my flight will be affected by the strike?

Comment: The people best placed to answer are Ryanair, but even they may not know until shortly before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe; AFAIK, It is a pilot strike then there is a big chance that the plane will be grounded.

"... They plan a 48-hour strike **from 00:01 on 22 August** until 23.59 on 23 August, and a 72-hour strike from 00:01 on 2 September until 23.59 on 4 September..."

"It’s highly likely though that some flights will not take off, and passengers who have booked flights, or are thinking of doing so, should check with the airline. **Ryanair tends to give passengers two or three days’ notice if their flight is cancelled**."

https://www.theguardian.com/business/2019/aug/08/ryanair-strike-when-does-it-start-flights-affected

Comment: Typical Ryanair. They advertise it as a 48-hour strike but you only get 47 hours and 58 minutes...